# Mouse trails on monitor connected to nVidia videocard in multi monitor setup on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 13.04, multiple-monitors

I have a problem on my PC w/ Ubuntu 13.04 (fresh virgin installation as of yesterday)

My Hardware spesifications:

- Asus P8Z77-M Pro mainboard
- Asus GeForce GT210 PCIe videocard
- 2x Philips 24" monitors at 1920x1080

Each monitor is connected to the HDMI-output of the videocards (so one to the onboard vcard of the mainboard and one to the GeForce vcard)

On the screen connected to the onboard vcard (set as primary screen in the BIOS) everything works perfect but on the screen connected to the GeForce vcard I have very irritating mouse trails and the screen behavior is abnormal (lag, refreshes take ages)

I tried installing the latest nVidia drivers but that messed up the Ubuntu installation completely and I decided to reinstall Ubuntu (no problem since I installed 1hr before)